# Check if file already exist in the same path

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I want to check if a specific file already exist in the same folder.
If it doesn't exist then create a new file and type in certain thing.
for example.  if filePath = test.txt and test.txt doesn't exist.
Create a new file name test.txt and put 12345 in the first line of the file.

Currently my method wont even run this if statement despite the condition is met. (test.txt does not exist)

```
    PrintWriter output;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if(!file.isFile()){
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new PersistenceException("Error!", ex);
        }
        output.print("12345");
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
```

Comment: You can use [exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) available to `File` objects.

Comment: And what if it does exist? And what if it exists but doesn't have the 12345?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a file exist or not by creating a File object and using exist method. File objects are different in java compared to C, when you create a File object you do not necessarily create a physical file.

```
File file = new File(pathString);
if (file.exists())
{
    //  File already exists
}
else
{
    //  You can create your new file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this condition in your if:

```
Files.exists(Paths.get(file))
```

You can decide to use the specification `NOFOLLOW_LINKS` in order to avoid to follow symbolic link.

This will help you to check if the file exists or not.

I hope this could help you.